# How to mount github on EC2

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2

I'm wondering that, instead of using clone, is there a way so I can "mount" my github repository on my EC2's webroot so every time I revise code in github my ec2 test server gets updated automatically?

P.S: It's a private repo.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

CI means that you have a server somewhere that is set up to monitor your repositories.
On each change, the CI server pulls the code, builds it and (possibly) uploads the result to your test server - it's all configurable.

Popular CI products are, for example:

- [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) *(open source)*
- [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) *(commercial product, but free for up to 20 projects)*